# IP address conversion using Python

Tags: python

I want to convert an ip address read from a file in the decimal format (192.168.65.72) to one in binary format {110000001010100001000001010001000}.I am reading the ip address in the decimal format from a file.Find the code snippet below.

```
/*contains 192.168.65.72*/
filter = open("filter.txt", "r")

for line in filter:
    bytePattern = "([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])"
    regObj = re.compile("\.".join([bytePattern]*4))
    for match in regObj.finditer(line):
        m1,m2,m3,m4 = match.groups()
        print "%s %s %s %s" %(m1, m2, m3, m4)
```

I want to convert m1,m2,m3 and m4 each into an 8bit binary value.I cannot figure out a way to do that.I am new to python.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm guessing that you either want the IP address as a plain old 32-bit integer, or you want 4 bytes of data holding an IP address.  I suspect you don't actually want a string containing 32 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
''.join([ bin(int(x))[2:].rjust(8,'0') for x in '123.123.123.123'.split('.')])
```

Comment: Be careful about required padding. Each byte in the IP needs to be represented by 8 bit, regardless of the value.

Comment: `''.join([bin(256 + int(x))[3:] for x in '123.123.123.123'.split('.')])`

Comment: @Omnifarious `bin(256 + int(x)` this is one god damn good idea :) +1

Comment: I am a python newbie.I tried the above thing but it gives
NameError: name 'bin' is not defined.
I googled bin function in python and came to know that it was a part of the python standard library.do i need to import any other package to get the python standard library?

Also what is the variable x supposed to mean? in the above explanation.It may not be the most intelligent question in the world but I do not understand it.

Thank very much in advance.
Cheers,
liv2hak

Comment: 1. No,you need not import anything to get `bin`. 
2. What is used in above answer is called *list comprehension*. You can read http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions.
If you don't understand something please let me know.
Best of luck!

Comment: thank you very much.I am able to get the desired output.cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Convert an IPv4 address from dotted-quad string format (for example, ‘123.45.67.89’) to 32-bit packed binary format:

[`socket.inet_aton`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton)`("192.168.65.72")`

Comment: It returns '\xc0\xa8AH'

Comment: @avi: Yes that's correct. That's a string literal representing the 4 bytes. I recommend you switch to Python3, which should more correctly return a bytes literal instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a string containing the raw data for the 32 bit IP address:

```
import struct
struct.pack('4B', *(int(x) for x in '123.123.123.123'.split('.')))
```

Or if you want a 32-bit integer containing the IP address:

```
import struct
struct.unpack('>I', struct.pack('4B', *(int(x) for x in '123.123.123.123'.split('.'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> bin( 192 )
'0b11000000'
```

String manipulation does the rest. Note however that in an IP all but the first parts are allowed to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `clean_ip()` from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/) if you read your file into a DataFrame. Install DataPrep with `pip install dataprep`.

```py
from dataprep.clean import clean_ip
df = pd.DataFrame({"ip": ["192.168.65.72", "123.123.123.123"]})

df2 = clean_ip(df, "ip", output_format="binary")
# print(df2)
                ip                          ip_clean
0    192.168.65.72  11000000101010000100000101001000
1  123.123.123.123  01111011011110110111101101111011
```